# Existence of Nth root, by Rudin soft question

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-explanation

I have a quick question: Why does Rudin choose to let $t=\frac {x}{x+1}$ so that $t<1$ ?

Indeed, Rudin States:

**Theorem**: For every real $x>0$ and every integer $n>0$ there is one and only one real $y$ such that $y^n=x$

**Proof**: 
That there is at most one such $y$ is clear, since $0<y_1<y_2$ implies $0<{y_1}^n<{y_2}^n$.

Let $E$ be the set of all positive real numbers $t$ such that $t^n<x$.
If $t=\frac {x}{x+1}$ then $0<t<1$. Thus $E$ is not empty.

He continues the proof which I understand, but how is it no loss of generality by making $t<1$ (I am guessing that there is a bijection between $[0;1]$ and $R$, if so how to make that rigorous, if not how does he allow himself to do such a thing).

Comment: Have you stated Rudin's theorem right? Take $x = 1$ and $n = 2$, then $y^n = x$ has **two** real solutions.

Comment: It should be *positive* real $y$ (following the argument given for unicity).

Comment: I stated the theorem word for word @RobArthan

Comment: Well in that case the statement is false. Are you sure you haven't omitted the word "positive"?

Comment: I am sure @RobArthan But that is beside the point, Rudin starts his proof by saying $0<y_1$ so that should cover it, but why does he pick such a way of representing $t$ such that $t<1$

Comment: The proof is not assuming that $t<1$. The proof is just showing that the set $E$ contains at least one number. It does so by explicitly showing you one such number that happens to be $<1$, that number is $x/(1+x)$. The very next step shows that $E$ is bounded from above by proving that $1+x$ is a bound.

Comment: It is well know and well-documented that Rudin mistakenly ommited that $y$ and $n$ are positive.  Toss the OP a little bread.  It's not his/her problem.

Comment: @fleablood: apologies, but if I see someone trying to prove an obviously false claim, then the first thing I want to do is agree with them what the claim should actually be. Unlike you, I haven't memorised the errata in Rudin, so I can't help without querying the data in the question.

Comment: I understand.  And it's fair.  But as the Theorem *is* true (when properly stated) and that isn't the problem the op has .... well, eventually the OP will have to ask "so the book is wrong; what am *I* supposed to do now?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At that point, all that Rudin wants to prove is that there is some $t>0$ such that $t^n<x$. Taking $t=\frac x{x+1}$ works, because $\frac x{x+1}<x$ and, since $\frac x{x+1}<1$,$$\left(\frac x{x+1}\right)^n\leqslant\frac x{x+1}<x.$$

Answer (score 2):

That he chose $t = \frac x{x+1}$ is only to show that $E = \{t > 0|t^2 < x\}$ is non-empty.  (because $\frac x{x+1} > 0$ and $(\frac {x}{x+1})^n < x$).  Any other  value would do.

He chooses $t$ to satisfy *two* conditions.  1) $0< t < 1$ and 2) $t < x$.  Therefore $t^n < t < x$.

If $x > 1$ then any $t \le 1$ would do as $t^n < t \le 1 < x$.

If $x \le 1$ then any $t < x$ will do as $t^n < t < x$.

But if you want to avoid doing *two* cases and just find *one* case then any $t < 1$ and $t < x$ will do as $t^n < t < x$.

So if it were me I'd say.  "Let $t < \min(1,x)$, say for example $t = .9*\min(1,x)$".

Rudin's a little more ... graceful.

If $t = \frac {x}{x+1}$ then $t < 1$ so $t^n < t$.  And $t < x$ so $t^n < t < x$.

In any event.  $E$ is not empty.

Comment: I am immensely appreciative of your response, thank you very much! Might you have in mind a more pedagogical analysis book to self-learn from?

Comment: Much as I hated Rudin as a student, I love it now and think it is the best to self learn.

Comment: I was afraid you would say that hahah!